# Format of Prediction for ROCR curves in R

Tags: r, prediction, predict, factors

It's my first time approaching ROCR curves in R, and using

```
#ROCR Curve
library(ROCR)

predict_rf <- predict(Model_RF, type = 'response')

ROCRpred_rf <- prediction(predict_rf, test.5$si2014)
ROCRperf_rf <- performance(ROCRpred_rf, 'tpr','fpr')
plot(ROCRperf_rf, colorize = TRUE, text.adj = c(train-0.2,1.7))
```

I got

```
> #ROCR Curve
> library(ROCR)
> 
> predict_rf <- predict(Model_RF, type = 'response')
> 
> ROCRpred_rf <- prediction(predict_rf, test.5$si2014)
Error in prediction(predict_rf, test.5$si2014) : 
  Format of predictions is invalid.
```

I'm using a RandomForest model to predict a factor variable (si2014).
This is the dataset I used for my predictions.

```
> sapply(test.5, class)
   spesa_tot     n_visite      importo        sesso eta_abbonati 
   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"    "numeric" 
      si2014     mesi_tot    Residenza      cluster 
   "numeric"    "integer"     "factor"     "factor"
```

What's the problem? With SVM model I've no problems at all....

Comment: try using `predict_rf <- predict(Model_RF, type = 'prob')` If does not work please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Now It says "ROCRpred_rf <- prediction(predict_rf, test.5$si2014)
Error in prediction(predict_rf, test.5$si2014) : 
  Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. 
It was easy. Just do

```
predict_rf <- predict(Model_RF, type = 'response')
predict_rf
ROCRpred_rf <- prediction(as.numeric(predict_rf), as.numeric(train.4$si2014))
ROCRperf_rf <- performance(ROCRpred_rf, 'tpr','fpr')
plot(ROCRperf_rf, colorize = TRUE, text.adj = c(train.4-0.2,1.7))
```

I modified

*ROCRpred_rf <- prediction(predict_rf, test.5$si2014)*

with

**ROCRpred_rf <- prediction(as.numeric(predict_rf), as.numeric(train.4$si2014))**